# Notation, a = b = number

Tags: symbols

If have some general equation $g(x) = k$ and here $k = 2$, so i wrote $g(x) = k = 2$, which looks not good. Is there some better math symbol for saying that $k = 2$ just in this case, maybe with different equal signs?

Comment: Not following exactly what you are asking. May be you want `\begin{align*} g(x) &= k\\ &=2 \\end{align*}` ?

Comment: I would keep a general equation separate from giving one side of the equation a particular value.

Comment: How do you want the equation to look? Maybe add an picture oder describer more detailed what you expect the output to look like

Comment: How about $g(x) = k |_{k=2}$ ?